# How to check if user is uploading/setting an image as a featured image?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I'm making a limitation for image upload based on @brasofilo [excellent snippet](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73921/13291). In short, it limits user to only uploading image with minimum dimension.

However I want to apply this only when user is uploading a featured image. I tried using `$pagenow` as a conditional,

```
global $pagenow;
if ($pagenow == 'media-upload.php')
    add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'wpse_28359_block_small_images_upload' );
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea here?

Answer (score 0):

Determining if an attachment actually is a *featured image* is easy:

```
get_post_thumbnail_id( get_post() );
```

which is a convenience function around

```
get_post_meta( get_post()->ID, '_thumbnail_id', true );
```

It is a bit more complicated if you know nothing than the File name or Url.

```
add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', function( $file ) {

    $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 
        get_post_thumbnail_id( get_post() ),
        'post-thumbnail'
    );

    // Output possible errors 
    if ( false !== strpos( $url, $file ) ) {
        $file['error'] = 'Sorry, but we only allow featured images';
    }

    return $file;
} );
```

As you can see, I do only compare the current file string with a posts featured image URl. Note that I do not know if this will work, it is not tested and the `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` might be too early.

Another option might be to use the last filter inside `_wp_handle_upload()`:

```
apply_filters( 'wp_handle_upload', array(
    'file' => $new_file,
    'url'  => $url,
    'type' => $type
), 'wp_handle_sideload' === $action ? 'sideload' : 'upload' );
```

which handles sideload as well.

In theory I assume it's too early to check if the featured image is actually the featured image before it is set. You might be able to revert the upload once it finished (delete file, reset post meta data), but that is far from elegant.

The meta box itself is registered with `add_meta_box()` and the box callback is `post_thumbnail_meta_box`, which calls `_wp_post_thumbnail_html()` to render the contents. When you look in there, you will see that there is actually a hidden field:

```
$content .= '<input type="hidden" id="_thumbnail_id" name="_thumbnail_id" value="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_id ? $thumbnail_id : '-1' ) . '" />';
```

Now the `name` is `_thumbnail_id`, which you should be able to fetch with `filter_input()` (good) or with `$_POST['_thumbnail_id']` (bad) inside a callback like `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` to determine if it actually was a featured image:

```
$featID = filter_input( INPUT_POST, '_thumbnail_id', … filters … );
```

Answer (score -2):

Add below code to your current theme's functions.php file, and it will limit minimum image dimensions:

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter','tc_handle_upload_prefilter');
function tc_handle_upload_prefilter($file)
{

    $img=getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
    $minimum = array('width' => '250', 'height' => '200');
    $width= $img[0];
    $height =$img[1];

    if ($width < $minimum['width'] )
        return array("error"=>"Image dimensions are too small. Minimum width is {$minimum['width']}px. Uploaded image width is $width px");

    elseif ($height <  $minimum['height'])
        return array("error"=>"Image dimensions are too small. Minimum height is {$minimum['height']}px. Uploaded image height is $height px");
    else
        return $file; 
}
```

Then just change the numbers of the minimum dimensions you want (in my example is 250 and 200)

Comment: How does that limit the restriction to only featured images?

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't limit the restriction to **only featured images**. I've got the image dimension script running. The thing I need is limiting it to only when you're setting up featured image. So adding image to post should not be limited.